# Upload PySpark Dataframe into a ION format file to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue

**Current issues:**

I can upload a PySpark dataframe into a compressed CSV file to S3. However, I want to test out DynamoDB import and see if I can upload ION format files to S3. The reason is that I have data in one column as BINARY, and ION is the only format that supports BINARY hence I chose to go with ION.

**What have I tried?**

Convert the column with a BINARY format to a BINARY STRING format, and it works. But, now I want to store that column in BINARY without converting to any other format.

Unfortunately, CSVs in my limited knowledge don't support BINARY data.
Hence, I had to look into saving these records in BINARY format in ION files(not sure if these exist). Or how would one go ahead doing this?
Another option is using AWS Glue, which I am sure solves my case, but I wanted to see what other things folks here suggest.

Comment: ION being a proprietary Amazon format, Pyspark does not support ION files.[link] (https://amazon-ion.github.io/ion-docs/index.html) - you can use a Lambda/Glue and write your code in python though. 

if you want to use CSV,  the files would have to store BINARY string and your program would cast into binary and that should work